# how to use overlays for ads784 joy-it 3.2 " tft screen

Tags: touchscreen

According to the manual from [Joy-it](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1200000-1299999/001283498-an-02-de-3_2_ZOLL_TOUCH_DISPLAY_RASPBERRY___KABEL.pdf) (cannot find an english version) I should download the latest firmware and use `modprobe` to load the kernel module but I receive an error message that the kernel module does not exist.

What I did:

`sudo REPO_URI=https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware rpi-update`

`sudo reboot`

`sudo modprobe ads7846_device verbose=2 cs=1 speed=2000000
model=7843 x_min=300 x_max=3800 y_min=700 y_max=3400 x_plate_ohms=60
pressure_max=255 gpio_pendown=17 keep_vref_on=1 swap_xy=1`

And I got the error that ads7846_device does not exist.

So I followed this post on [github](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/260):

I could not compile the ads7846-overlay.dts file due to an error:

`sudo dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o ads7846-overlay.dtb ads7846-overlay.dts`

`FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree`

However the `ads7846-overlay.dtb` file is already present in `/boot/overlays`

So I edited the `/boot/config.txt` file accordingly:

`# enable the 3.2 " TFT screen
dtdebug=1
device_tree=ads7846-overlay.dtb
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,speed=2000000,model=7843,xmin=300,xmax=3800,ymin=700,ymax=3400,x_plate_ohms=60,pressure_max=255,gpio_pendown=17,keep_vref_on=1,swap_xy`

However, `sudo vcdbg log msg | grep Loading` gives me following error:

`001335.223: Failed to load overlay 'ads7846'

What I haven`t even tried yet is to load the overlay for the fbtft module (sainsmart32). Any ideas what might cause the error ?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same issue: The correct manual can be downloaded from [this link](http://files.voelkner.de/1300000-1399999/001380381-an-01-de-8_13_CM__3_2__TOUCH_DISPLAY_320X240_PX.pdf).

Basically, it is a waveshare device:

Modify `config.txt`:

`dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=waveshare32b
:rotate=270`

Add `fbcon=map:10` to the end of the first line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Create `sudo nano 
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` and add

`Section "InputClass"
Identifier "calibration"
MatchProduct "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
Option "Calibration" "160 3723 3896 181"
Option "SwapAxes" "1"
EndSection`

Change `fb0` to `fb1` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf` (change of output from HDMI to the Display)

Clone `git clone https://github.com/swkim01/waveshare-dtoverlays.git` and copy all .dtb files to `/boot/overlays`

Get the latest drivers `sudo REPO_URI=https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware rpi-update`

Afterwards you just have to enable autologon with `raspi-config`

Screen is working. Touch feature not yet. Just found [this tutorial](http://hardware-libre.fr/2015/07/review-guide-waveshare-sainsmart-3-2-inch-rpi-lcd/) which describes the whole process in english.

Answer (score 0):

The line device_tree=ads7846-overlay.dtb appears to be wrong.

Try removing that line.